# ! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> }

Tags: errors, equations, systeme

```
\begin{eqnarray}[\{]
$$\frac{\partial{x_i}}{\partial{q_j}} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\frac{\partial{x_i}}{\partial{q_j}}  $$ \\
$$\frac{\partial{y_i}}{\partial{q_j}} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\frac{\partial{y_i}}{\partial{q_j}}  $$ \\
$$\frac{\partial{z_i}}{\partial{q_j}} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\frac{\partial{z_i}}{\partial{q_j}}  $$
\end{eqnarray}
```

I don't see the fault here. Could you guys please help me ??

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Even dolls can...

Comment: your use of `eqnarray` is very wrong ... remove all `$` and than try again. if you will provide complete but small document we can easily show how to correct type your system of equations.

Comment: @Hitman01, anyway consider other part of my comment. `eqnarray` is considered obsolete. try to use environment from `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Hitman01: See [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `eqnarray`, as it leads to bad spacings. Use the `amsmath` environments instead. I suppose you're after this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrace\;]{align}
\diffp{x_i}{{q_j}} & = \smash[t]{\sum_{j = 1}^{n}}\diffp{x_i}{{q_j}} \\
\diffp{y_i}{{q_j}} & = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\diffp{y_i}{{q_j}} \\
\diffp{z_i}{{q_j}} & = \smash[b]{\sum_{j = 1}^{n}}\diffp{z_i}{{q_j}}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

or with use `cases` package;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{}
\diffp{x_i}{{q_j}} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\diffp{x_i}{{q_j}} \\
\diffp{y_i}{{q_j}} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\diffp{y_i}{{q_j}} \\
\diffp{z_i}{{q_j}} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\diffp{z_i}{{q_j}}
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]